# Identify and summarize broken hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Fair warning, this is my first Stack Overflow question:

I have a sheet with several hyperlinks in both cells and shapes.  We are about to rearrange our files to better organize folders which is going to break some of these links.  I found a helpful Q/A on Stack Overflow which walked me through building a sub to check if a link is broken and highlight it.

My question is how can I determine the anchor of the broken link?

I want to create a new sheet in the workbook "broken_hyper" which lists all of the broken links throughout the entire workbook and creates a hyperlink (or even a description) back to where I can find and fix the broken link.

I tried using

```
If objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then

    alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = alink.Parent
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlink.Add _
        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2), _
        Address:=alink.Parent
        i = i + 1
End If
```

However, I can't find any property under `.parent` other than `.cells.row` or `.cells.column` that locates the anchor easily.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am no professional - everything I've picked up thus far was from the helpful answers from people like you, so thanks for that.

Comment: `aLink.Parent` points to a cell, you will obviously not find the anchor there. Try searching directly in `aLink`

Comment: I'm looking for the cell that `alink.parent` is in so I can set the new hyperlink `address:=` "alink.parent cell string" so anyone can just click on the link to navigate to the broken hyperlink.

Comment: By _anchor_ do you mean the cell the (broken) link is in?

Comment: Right I want to find the broken link and then reference that cell in a new link on a new sheet.  In other words I want the broken link's anchor to be the address of the new link.  Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.Address` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx)

```
If objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then

    alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = alink.Parent
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlink.Add _
        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2), _
        Address:=alink.Parent.Address
        i = i + 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I want to link back to the cell where the original link was.  Basically this program is finding all of the broken links and creating a list of them.  I want a new link back to the broken link's location (the worksheet is long) so I don't have to hunt for it.  If possible I'd like to use a property of `alink` to create the `:=address` argument for the new hyperlink.

Comment: Ok so `alink.parent.address` is giving me exactly what I need.  I am just struggling with actually getting vba to create the new hyperlink now.  Thanks for your help!